# How to force a 302 redirect to index.html when hosting on S3?

Tags: 301-redirect, static-content, amazon-s3

I've found that the following two URLs will show the same content:

```
http://example.com/blog/
http://example.com/blog/index.html
```

In the case of the first URL, it appears to pick up the `index.html` from the `blog` pseudo-folder. I guess this is because I have `index.html` configured as my index document.

However, the browser is not redirected. This means I end up with two different URLs being hit for the same content. From the point of view of analytics and other things this is a pain.

Can I make S3 redirect with a 301 to index.html? Or the other way around?

Comment: What about... Don't create links to /blog/index.html.  link to /blog/.  (with the trailing slash, otherwise S3 will send a 301 to append it.)  Showing the index document implicitly and explicitly is essentially standard web server behavior.

Comment: "Showing the index document implicitly and explicitly is essentially standard web server behavior." -> can you provide a reference for that? I'm interested...

Comment: Navigating to `/blog` redirects to `/blog/` so that relative paths of documents under "/blog/" work correctly as links.  The subsequent request for `/blog/` then displays the content of `/blog/index.html` (implicit) without it being reflected in the address bar.  Navigating to `/blog/index.html` shows the same content (explicit).   I can't provide a reference, just anecdotal observations of 18 years of working with web servers... Apache, Nginx, IIS, S3 with static hosting, and any number of relatively minor players... when an index/default document is defined, that's what they do.

Comment: Hmmm... not so sure. That's an implementation detail of the server, and the server could easily be made to work in a different way (`mod` script for Apache, or whatever). What I meant by a reference was a citation from one of the the HTTP RFCs or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, make sure you are only linking to one version of the URL, whether it is `/blog/` or `/blog/index.html` (I'd prefer the former since it's shorter and simpler).

The best solution with regards to SEO would be to use a canonical tag. Put this inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://yoursite.com/blog/">
```

That means that when search engines see both URLs they are treated the same, and ensures visitors coming from a search engine will hit `/blog/` and not `/blog/index.html`.

If you have links from other sites you may not be able to control where the visitors land, so for analytics purposes it's probably still worth redirecting the user.

I don't know if you have any kind of server-side rules in your situation given that it's a static site, but if you can use `.htaccess` you should do something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/index.html /blog/
```

Finally, if all else fails then redirecting the user with JavaScript is fine:

```
<script>
if (window.location.href.indexOf('index.html') != -1)
    window.location.href = '/blog/';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed most of this. Unfortunately the `.htaccess` redirection is not possible. I have changed all links to `/`, and added both a redirection and a `link rel=canonical` to the `index.html` pages. I also had to migrate all my Disqus comments. I won't mark as answered, because the question isn't really answered, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

place in your /blog/index.html on the top, before opening < head>

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:http://www.example.com/index.html");
?>
```

so you get the only one url: with index.html on the end - all tries to come into /blog/ will be redirected to /blog/index.html

On hosting, which doesn't support PHP, use a Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.example.com/blog/index.html";
//–>
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not using PHP, this is a static site hosted on S3.

Comment: i edited the post